# Basic web tweaks that all applications should have

Tags: go

Currently my web app is just a router and handlers.

What are some important things I am missing to make this production worthy?

1. I believe I have to set the # of procs to ensure this uses maximum goroutines?
2. Should I be using output buffering?

Anything else you see missing that is best-practise?

```
var (
  templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/home.html")
)

func main() {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/", WelcomeHandler)

  http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r)
}

func WelcomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homePage, err := api.LoadHomePage()
    if err != nil {
    }
    tmpl := "home"
    renderTemplate(w, tmpl, homePage)
}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, hp *HomePage) {

    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl+".html", hp)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to set/change [`runtime.GOMAXPROCS()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) as since Go 1.5 it defaults to the number of available CPU cores.
2. Buffering output? From the performance point of view, you don't need to. But there may be other considerations for which you may.

For example, your `renderTemplate()` function may potentially panic. If executing the template starts writing to the output, it involves setting the HTTP response code and other headers prior to writing data. And if a template execution error occurs after that, it will return an error, and so your code attempts to send back an error response. At this point HTTP headers are already written, and this [`http.Error()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error) function will try to set headers again => panic.

One way to avoid this is to first render the template into a buffer (e.g. [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)), and if no error is returned by the template execution, then you can write the content of the buffer to the response writer. If error occurs, then of course you won't write the content of the buffer, but send back an error response just like you did.

To sum it up, your code is production ready performance-wise (excluding the way you handle template execution errors).

Comment: The template -> buffer trick is a good one (I just wanted to second that). You can also (if you're not being a HTTP reverse proxy) use the gzip middleware from [gorilla/handlers](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers) to gzip responses, as well as logging & panic recovery. Those won't speed things up, but they'll help make your application more robust.

Answer (score 0):

1. `WelcomeHandler` should return when `err != nil` is true.
2. Log the error when one is hit to help investigation.
3. Place `templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/home.html")` in the `init`. Split it into separate lines. If `template.ParseFiles` returns an then error make a `Fatal` log. And if you have multiple templates to initialize then initialize them in goroutines with a common `WaitGroup` to speed up the startup.
4. Since you are using mux, *[HTTP Server is too clean with its URLs](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/zWPOOJjCgNQ/discussion)* might also be good to know.
5. You might also want to reconsider the decision of letting the user's know why they got the `http.StatusInternalServerError` response.
6. Setting the `GOMAXPROCS` > 1 if you have more the one core would definitely be a good idea but I would keep it less than number of cores available.